# Validating all ascii codes are printed from compiled C program with strace

Tags: c, hex, ascii, strace

I'm making a program where eventually I can send out any set of ascii codes to a custom external hardware device.

What I want to do is ensure that any set of characters I output are actually outputted. As a test, I made this program to try to output every ascii value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  int n;
  char Q[1000];
  char V[100];
  V[1]='\0';
  for (n=0;n<256;n++){
    sprintf(V,"%c",n);
    Q[n]=V[0];
  }
  Q[n]=0;
  printf("Result = %s",Q);
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling and running strace on the program, I get this at the end:

```
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7f4f000
write(1, "Result = "..., 9Result = )             = 9
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

So it sortof is trying to tell me the correct output but how can I make it so all codes are outputted, and therefore I see:

```
write(1, "Result = \00\01\02\03\04\05\....
```

with all codes all the way until \255 ?

I also changed n from 0 to 1 to skip the null character in hopes that printf will print everything but that did not work.

Comment: You are aware of "Non-Printable" ASCII characters, No? You can use a lookup table for those less than `' '` (space - `0x20`) and `127` (del) and output the description in its place. (e.g. `"nul", "soh", "stx", ...` for `0, 1, 2, ...`) See, e.g. [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Note: there are only 128 [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters.

Comment: Also, what do string functions look for to indicate end-of-string? (hint: a *nul-character*) What is the first character in `Q`? (hint: a *nul-character*). How many characters will `printf` see in the string `Q` using the `"%s"` conversion specifier to output string `Q`? (hint: ... you get the drift...)

Comment: Here is an example [ASCII Table Generator](http://susepaste.org/75357399). Link expires: Tue May 28 23:53:43 CDT 2019